# How does Subsonic handle connections?

Tags: .net, subsonic

In Nhibernate you start a session by creating it during a BeginRequest and close at 
EndRequest

```
public class Global: System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

    protected static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return new Configuration()
            .Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get{ return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["current.session"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Global()
    {
        BeginRequest += delegate
        {
            CurrentSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        };
        EndRequest += delegate
        {
            if(CurrentSession != null)
                CurrentSession.Dispose();
        };
    }
}
```

What’s the equivalent in Subsonic?

The way I understand, Nhibernate will close all the connections at endrequest.

***Reason:*** While trouble shooting some legacy code in a Subsonic project I get a lot of MySQL timeouts,suggesting that the code is not closing the connections

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:
>   error connecting: Timeout expired. The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to
>   obtaining a connection from the pool.
>   This may have occurred because all
>   pooled connections were in use and max
>   pool size was reached. Generated: Tue,
>   11 Aug 2009 05:26:05 GMT
>   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException:
>   Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:
>   error connecting: Timeout expired. 
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   obtaining a connection from the pool. 
>   This may have occurred because all
>   pooled connections were in use and max
>   pool size was reached.    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
>   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>   at
>   SubSonic.MySqlDataProvider.CreateConnection(String
>   newConnectionString)    at
>   SubSonic.MySqlDataProvider.CreateConnection()
>   at
>   SubSonic.AutomaticConnectionScope..ctor(DataProvider
>   provider)    at
>   SubSonic.MySqlDataProvider.GetReader(QueryCommand
>   qry)    at
>   SubSonic.DataService.GetReader(QueryCommand
>   cmd)    at
>   SubSonic.ReadOnlyRecord`1.LoadByParam(String
>   columnName, Object paramValue)

My connection string is as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xx" connectionString="Data Source=xx.net; Port=3306; Database=db; UID=dbuid; PWD=xx;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=12;Min Pool Size=2;Connection Lifetime=60" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always a one-time shot unless you specifically wrap your stuff with a "SharedDbConnectionScope". I've seen this before - specifically while testing MySQL on windows - and the problem is that the MySQL driver is buggy and doesn't shut off connections.

I was able to repro this by creating a console app and a basic reader then looping over it - bam. ConnectionPool errors.

Not much of an answer, I know, but what can ya do.

Comment: Rob, I didn't understand this part = "It's always a one-time shot unless you specifically wrap your stuff with a "SharedDbConnectionScope". ". How do I do this?. Can you point me to an example?

Comment: So if I don't want to open & close lots of connections I have to use this SharedDbConnectionScope? That seems quite important!! Do you know if I still need a TransactionScope if I don't care about transactions?

Answer (score 4):

I have run into the same style of error before with using SubSonic incorectly.  We had a piece of Javascript that pinged the server every 2 or so minutes just to keep our session alive and when it pinged the server a call to our Membership was made that used a DataReader.  Anyway long story short we weren't closing the reader and the little keep alive script would slowly eat up all of our 160 allowed connections even with only a handful of users.  You may want to check to see if you are using SubSonic in that way(returning IDataReader from queries and then not disposing of them)